# Вход на сайт с разных страниц пользователей с разными ролями

Tags: php, symfony3, fosuserbundle

Добрый день. Люди знающие, подскажите.

В системе есть пользователи с разными ролями (ADMIN, USER). Необходимо сделать вход для этих пользователей с разных страниц (/admin/login, /login).
Добавил в security.yml

```
firewalls:
    ....
    admin:
        pattern: ^/admin(.*)
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
            target: /
        anonymous: true
access_control:
    ....
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Создал AdminController.php в нем loginAction(), к нему прописал route: /admin/login - форма отображается. Никак не могу понять где обрабатывать и перехватывать пользователя для проверки прав.
Или я не в том направлении двигаюсь.

Подскажите кто знает, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Симфони самостоятельно обрабатывает сабмит формы авторизации. Работа контроллера сводится к двум задачам:

- Показать форму логина при GET запросе к `login_path` (/admin/login).
- Отобразить ошибки в случае ввода некорректных данных.

Форма авторизации обычно соответствует следующим соглашениям:

- Элемент `<form>` отправляет POST запрос на роут логина, определенный в ключе `login_path`.
- Поле содержащее имя пользователя имеет атрибут `name="_username"`, а поле пароля атрибут `name="_password"`.

Если форма авторизации соответствует описанным выше критериям, дополнительной настройки для нее не потребуется. В противном случае необходимо будет уточнить конфигурацию `form_login`. Детали можно узнать в разделе документации [Form login configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-form-login)

Авторизация с использованием формы описана в  разделе [How to Build a Traditional Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) текущей документации.